# Ordinal Logistic Regression is not giving reasonable results

Tags: logistic, ordinal-data, ordered-logit

I am quite new to this kind of statistics, so please be kind to me!

I am currently trying to use statsmodels to run an ordinal logistic regression(https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/ordinal_regression.html). My dependant variable has three categories (ordered, "proximal" < "transitional" < "distal") and I have independent variables which are extremely zero-inflated. I have ~400 such independent variables and I want to test each separately. I plan to fit a model with each and do some posthoc multiple testing corrections.

The problem is, I am getting results which don't seem reasonable to me. (Either that, or I am misunderstanding the model I am using).

One potential problem is that my samples (~900) are not evenly distributed between the categories of the dependent variable:

proximal - 700
transitional - 180
distal - 44

As a test, I am just showing two models with 1 independent variable (called "SAT1") that should be highly predictive  and one variable that should not be predictive (called "HSPA1B"). I am saying this because one of the variable has a clear trend between the categories that follows the order, and the other doesn't.

The first set of plots is for the variable I expect to be more predictive, and the bottom is for the variable that I do not expect to be predictive. (Maybe predictive is not the right word).

[image]

[image]

I am fitting the models as follows:

```
model = OrderedModel(independent, dependent, distr='logit')
res = model.fit(method='bfgs', disp=False)
res.summary()
```

The independent variable is a pandas series with dtype categorical and is ordered as required by statsmodels.

Here is the output for the first variable that trends with the categories:

[image]

Here is the output for the 2nd variable, which does not trend with the data:
[image]

Why are they both significant?

Comment: What are the variables or statistics on the axes of the plots? My guess is that there is still an upward trend in the second variable between proximal and transitional that can make the coefficient statistically significant.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Each plot is a histogram of the variables (top and bottom) for samples in the proximal transitional distal. The x axis is the variable and y is the count. So, it's not necessarily incorrect to use zero-inflated data like this in an ordinal logit? Thanks